# How to list all ORecordBytes in OrientDB?

Tags: orientdb

I'm using the ORecordBytes to store binaries and like to list them all but the command select * from ORecordBytes is not recognised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select all ORecordBytes stored in OrientDB using the SQL command :

```
select * from cluster:default
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see I have a class with binary data:

[image]

To see them you can do a select of the cluster in which they are stored, in this case it's `select from cluster:3`

This is the result:

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: On my console select * return nothing but select count(*) will return the number of entries. Data are of type []byte. Any idea ?